# .gitignore debug files in asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, git, gitignore

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application. To get everything started, I created a new repo and pushed "all" my changes as the initial commit. This initial commit also contained all the debug files that were generated when I was creating / testing my project (before committing).

How do I add the debug files in my `.gitignore` file?

I want to ignore all changes in the following directories. This is also what I have in my `.gitignore` file

```
my_project/bin
my_project/obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using github, you can initialize your repository using CSharp .ignore like below:[image]

If not you can use a copy of it from [CSharp ignore gist](https://gist.github.com/YogirajA/6032546)

It works well for all of my asp.net projects. It saved me from these types of issues.

**Edit:**

For the existing project or files you can follow the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring) to apply the new git ignore.

Comment: @FarhanAhmad awesome! No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following two lines to .gitignore:

```
my_project/bin/
my_project/obj/
```

Plus you have to git rm -r both directories beforehand. If you want to keep them, but not change them later: you need to move them somewhere else, delete them with git rm -r, commit it and then place them again. Then, thanks to created .gitignore file, git won't track those directories anymore.

**Edit:**

Actually

```
my_project/bin
my_project/obj
```

should work too.